# Existence confirmation method of the table of MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to confirm whether there is a certain table.
When create a table, there is an SQL sentence such as DROP TABLE IF EXISTS xxx_tb.
Will there be the method that can identify the existence of the table by SQL likewise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable';
```

Should be portable across most databases.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [SHOW TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-tables.html) command of MySQL:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'xxx_tb';
```

Comment: Just be aware that this is case sensitive!

Comment: It's always best to be aware of case, but on systems without case sensitivity, that's not true: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

Or indeed, you  can just do a query like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE 1=0
```

Which will give an error (see documentation for exact error code, or try it) if the table doesn't exist, but succeed with no results if it does.